# Using Composer image locally?

Tags: php, docker, composer-php

As far as I understand the [official composer image](https://hub.docker.com/_/composer) is meant to be used as a is php management tool and not like any other images you can use within the docker-compose file. So basically I can use the docker container if I don't have or don't want to install composer locally / natively.

So, I have created a root directory for my app which is empty at the moment, but if I run for example `docker run --rm -it -volume $PWD:/app composer create-project laravel/laravel .` I can't see the Laravel app being installed within my directory. Have I misunderstood something, or any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should either use the flag -v or --volume.
This command worked for me, just make sure you are in an empty directory:

```
docker run --rm -it -v $PWD:/app composer create-project laravel/laravel .
```